# TypeError: products.data is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am beginner to MERN stack and I am trying to get card details from database and display them in cards.I got this error 'TypeError: products.data is undefined', Before that, I got TypeError: products.map is not a function. So I added [] inside useState. I can fetch data from Mongodb through Postman. Please help me to fix this code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';


export default function Gents() {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => { 
  
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getProduct')
    .then(res => {
      if(res.data.status === 'success' && res.data.product){
        setProducts(res.data.data.product);
      }else{
        setError('Unexpected response format from server');
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if(err.response && err.response.status === 403){
        setError('Access Denied');
      }else{
        setError('Error fetching from server');
      }
    });
  },[]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Gents</h1>
      {products && 
        products.map((product,index) => (
        <ProductCard key={index}
        id={product._id}
        img = {product.img}
        title = {product.title}
        prize = {product.prize}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the Card component

```
import React from 'react'
//import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { Button, CardActionArea, CardActions } from '@mui/material';


export default function ProductCard({img,title,prize}) {

  var cardStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    width: '30vw',
    height: '45vw',
    
}
  return (
    <div>
         <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }} style={cardStyle}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          image={img}
          alt="green iguana"
          sx={{height:500}}
        />
        <CardContent paddingTop={'500'}>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h4" component="div"  paddingTop={'500px'}>
            {title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5" color="text.secondary">
            Rs: {prize}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="medium" variant="contained" sx={{bgcolor:"#c85959", "&:hover":{bgcolor:"#4f0b0b"}}}>
          Shop Now
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the getProduct Route

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Product = require("../database/models/Product")

router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.find({});
    try{
        res.json(product);
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            status: 'Failed', 
        });
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Please help me to fix this code.

Comment: Still the same error product.data not defined

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: always same error

Comment: it's still the same error 'TypeError: products.data is undefined', I can fetch data through postman

Comment: I have changed the code (useEffect) as above and got the error, Unexpected response format from server. Still I couldn't find what's wrong..

Comment: Instead of `res.data.data.product`, you should use `res.data`. because you use `res.json(product)`.

Answer (score 0):

**getProduct**

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const Product = require("../database/models/Product")

router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
  const product = await Product.find({});
  try {
    res.json(product);
  } catch(err) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**useEffect**

```js
// provided that products can be found
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getProduct')
.then(res => { setProducts(res.data); })
.catch(err => { setError(`${err.name} - ${err.message}`); }
```